# Visual Basic User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA with excel to open certain web pages and if an IDelement is found save the page number to an Excel cell but I keep getting compile error: User-defined type not defined

Sub PullMoh()

```
Dim IE  As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim ws  As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
Dim pn     'page number
Dim mypage 'The default page
Dim RowCount

'Start at row number #
RowCount = 2

For pn = 342542 To 343235
    x = 1
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    mypage = "https://" & pn & "/edit/320189/320225"
    IE.Navigate mypage

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document

    'If webpage invalid make x = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    IsNull (doc.getElementById("edit-field-north-side-und-0-value").Value)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        x = 0
    End If

    'Create if statement to check the element
    If x <> 0 Then
        ws.Range("A" & RowCount) = pn
        ws.Range("B" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-unit-no-und-0-value").Value    'Get unit number
        ws.Range("C" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-floor-no-und-0-value").Value   'Get Level number
        ws.Range("D" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-zooning-section-und").Value    'Get Division number
        ws.Range("E" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-north-side-und-0-value").Value 'Get North
        ws.Range("F" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-east-side-und-0-value").Value  'Get East
        ws.Range("G" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-south-side-und-0-value").Value 'Get South
        ws.Range("H" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-west-side-und-0-value").Value  'Get West
        ws.Range("I" & RowCount).Value = doc.getElementById("edit-field-unit-area-und-0-value").Value  'Get Unit Area
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    End If

    IE.Quit

Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Did you establish a reference to the relevant library?

Comment: ^ Or use `Object` if you want to late-bind.

Comment: Yes it's referenced and I used similar code before with different setup but now I keep getting that error, sorry I'm new to VBA @JohnColeman

Comment: Are you sure that your project has a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`? Adding that reference will silence the error in `Dim doc As HTMLDocument` (though you will then find at least one more error further down in your code).

Comment: Yes you are right Microsoft HTML Object Library was not added to the reference, I added another reference based on a solution I read on another website.

Comment: changed nothing to Null, I run the code but another issue run-time error '424: Object required and it refers to npage = mypage.Insert(49, pn) @JohnColeman

Comment: `mypage = "https://"` defines `mypage` to be a simple string, not an object which corresponds to a web page.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowlege I only startes using VB couple of days ago to do a certain task , yes it's defined as a string, the code open an internet exploer page and supposed to navigate to it, but it just open the page but don't navigate, so how should I solve it @JohnColeman

Comment: What is your intention in `npage = mypage.Insert(49, pn)` ? Strings don't have an insert method (or any other method for that matter, they are not objects in VBA). Are you trying to take the string `mypage` and insert `pn` in it, starting at index 49?

Comment: If you are trying to insert, something like: `npage = Mid(mypage,1,49) & pn & Mid(mypage,50)` (with perhaps needing to tweak the indices by 1 to avoid an off-by-one error). VB.Net has strings which are objects with an insert method. VBA is an older but syntactically similar language. If you aren't aware of the difference, it is easy to find an online resource with VB.Net code while thinking that you are getting VBA code, so you need to be careful.

Comment: npage = mypage.Insert(49, pn) , the intention to insert the pn number into mypage at index 49, I tried the code alone using insert and it worked, i put it in a for loop also and it worked. I will try it the same way you describet if it didn't workout I guess I will have to check online resources

Comment: "I tried the code alone using insert and it worked" -- how could it work when it throws an `Object required` error? Your comments seem to be inconsistent.

Comment: I was able to solve it using & &